# What are the parameters of protonation of a molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, grignard-reagent

[image]

Adding an acid replaces the $\ce{-MgBr+}$ with an $\ce{H+}$. Why does this happen? Is $\ce{H+}$ a better electrophile than $\ce{MgBr+}$?

Or, to put it another way, why doesn't $\ce{MgBr}$ stays attached to $\ce{O}$?

Comment: Well, it's symbolic scheme of reaction not telling what exactly Mg(OH)Br in H2O/t-butanol solution "looks like". t-butanolate isn't monomer and hydroxide is solvated, but those are kinda details.

Comment: Isn't that a Grignard reagent? If so, it's a strong base and a nucleophile, isn't it? Making the intermediate carbocation less stable, more reactive with acidic hydrogens?

Answer (score -2):

We are taking about electrophilicity of ions.
It basically depends upon:
1. charge on the ion(+)
2. density of plus charge on it

So comparing $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{CH3+}$, the former has a higher plus charge density so that's why it will be more attracted towards 'O'.